# Return back to different controllers from one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, controller

I have entities BookShelf and Book. Routing is: `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Url for getting books from shelf with Id=2 is

```
.../BookShelves/ManageBookShelves?shelfId=2
```

When books are returned, it is possible to click on name of book and view details about book. This is action method of another controller:

```
.../Books/Details/1
```

There is link on view Details for returning back to Index method:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
```

It works ok when I get on view Details directly from BooksController. But when I get there from BookShelvesController, I need to return back to list of books on particular shelf, here:

```
.../BookShelves/ManageBookShelves?shelfId=2
```

The question is how to make view return back depeding on called action/controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Books and BookShelves has a one to one relationship. That means, one book may be part of only one book shelve. In this case, you must be storing each book againist a book shelve in your db table, thus you will have a `BookShelveId` in your Book table ( and the Book entity class).

In your BookDetails page, when you get a Book record/entity , simply use the BookShelveId property value to build the Back link.

Assuming your BookViewModel looks like this

```
public class BookViewModel
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Title { set;get;}
   public int ShelveId {set;get;}
}
```

From your Details action method, set the ShelveId as well.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
   var book=db.Books.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Id==id);
   if(book!= null)
   {
     var vm=new BookViewModel { Id=id,Title=book.Title,ShelveId=book.BookShelveId};
     return View(vm);
   }
   return View("NotFound");
}
```

Now in your view, Use the `ShelveId` of the view model inside `Html.ActionLink` method to generate the back link.

```
@model BookViewModel
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back","ManageBookShelves","BookShelves",
                                           new {shelfId=Model.ShelveId},null)
</p>
```

**EDIT :** *As per the comment.*
If you prefer to have different back button behavior based on from where the link was clicked, you may pass that information in the query string.

So from the Books index page

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Details","Details","Book", new {@id=item.Id},null)
```

And from the BookShelve page

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Details","Details","Book",
                new {@id=item.Id,shelveId=Model.BookShelveId },null)
```

Now have your Details method accepts 2 params and one is nullable and we will make the ShelveId nullable.

```
public class BookViewModel
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Title { set;get;}
   public int? ShelveId {set;get;}
}
```

and the action method.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id, int? shelveId)
{
  var vm = new BookViewModel{ Id=id };
  // to do : Get book entity and map to view model.(Except the ShelveId property)
  if(shelveId!=null)
  {
    vm.ShelveID=shelveId;
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

And in the view, now check the ShelveId property and render the links

```
@model BookViewModel
@if(Model.ShelveId==null)
{
  <p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to books","Index","Book")</p>
}
else
{
  <p>@Html.ActionLink("View Details","Details","Book",
                new {@id=item.Id,shelveId=Model.BookShelveId },null)</p>
}
```

Comment: I can get this view in two ways: 
1) directly from Books/Details/id; when I click on "Back", I should return to Books/Index; 2) from /BookShelves/ManageBookShelves?shelfId and then Books/Details/id. here when I click on "Back", I should return to BookShelves/ManageBookShelves?shelfId. How to combine this two variants?